# 'struct objc_object' has no member named 'position'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So I have this class called a `Cell` which is a subclass of `CCSprite` then I have three other subclasses of `Cell`.

In one of the subclasses I am overriding a method called `addCellToCell` in class `Cell`:

```
-(void)addCellToCell:(id)_cell;
```

And I am trying to do this:

```
    self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Jet.png"];
    [self setPosition:ccp(_cell.position.x+5, _cell.position.y)];
```

Where I am trying to set the object `self`'s position (which since it is inheriting from `Cell` it makes it essentially a modified `CCSprite`) relative to another `Cell` subclassed object (potentially from any one of the three subclasses).

But when I do this I get the error:

> request for member 'position' in '_cell', which is of non-class type 'objc_object*'

It also suggest I use "->" instead of "." so I change it to that:

> 'struct objc_object' has no member
>   named 'position'

Sorry if it is confusing... Please ask for any clarification if you need some. How can I fix these errors?

Definition of Cell class:

```
@interface Cell : CCSprite {
}

-(void)addToCell:(id)_cell;

@end
```

Comment: What is the definition of the `Cell` class?

Comment: Where does this assignment to self happen? In the initializer? If it happens anywhere else, I'd be suspicious. And if its in the initializer, then you have at least an unusual style... Do you really mean to assign self a new value in the snippet posted?

Comment: @Dirk: It is not in the initializer.

Comment: @Espresso: No. It's is just a method argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to `Cell` object before using it,

```
Cell aCell = (Cell *)_cell;
```

and then

```
[self setPosition:ccp(aCell.position.x+5, aCell.position.y)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
-(void)addCellToCell:(id)_cell;
```

to

```
-(void)addCellToCell:(Cell*)_cell;
```

**Don't use** `id` **unless absolutely necessary.** Always use  `ClassName*` instead.